# Post status on wall using Facebook SDK 3.0 in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to post status update on my wall using Facebook SDK 3.0 in android. The login session is perfect everything work just fine except the posting part.

After giving the permission to write to wall. Doesn't post to wall. When I check on the active session part. I get open_token_updated instead of "OPENED" in logs - Before giving the permission to write - log shows "OPENED"...

If I close the application and load the application again I can see "OPENED" and I am able to post to wall.

Here is what I am trying:

```
check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            boolean login = false;
            if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
            {
                login = true;
            }

            Log.e ("Session Active?", "" + Session.getActiveSession().getState());

        }

    });

            //POST WALL BUTTON
    post.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           if(Session.getActiveSession() != null)
 {
                     if(Session.getActiveSession().getState()==SessionState.OPENED)
                    publishStory();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is publish method

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null)
    {

        // Check for publish permissions
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions))
        {
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            //return;
        }

        Log.e("after", "permissions");

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "Sample Test from my app");
        postParams.putString("caption", "The best");
        postParams.putString("description","Testing how it works.");
        postParams.putString("link", "http://www.google.com/");
        postParams.putString("picture", "http://www.etftrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/blue_wave_of_water-wide.jpg");

        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback()
        {
            public void onCompleted(Response response)
            {
                Log.e("post response",response.toString());

                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Log.e ("No", "Not null");

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e ("No", "null");

                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try
                    {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                        Toast.makeText(Sessionvalid.this, postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        Log.i("JSON", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                }


            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }
```

SubSetMethod

```
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset)
{
    for (String string : subset)
    {
        if (!superset.contains(string))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

OnActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I am doing something wrong here.. Not sure where and how to fix this??